# Pytelegrambotapi Throws ReadTimeout error

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm currently developing a Telegram bot using python/Pytelegrambotapi.
In my local machine, if the bot is started and left for sometime without any request, It terminates and throws the error
`requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=25)`

Can someone help me handling this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sometime network or Telegram issues happen.

Handle exceptions or use bot.infinity_polling() instead of bot.polling()

edit: Try this function with these parameters (you can adjust later as you'd like)

> bot.infinity_polling(timeout=10, long_polling_timeout = 5)

Comment: Tried bot.infinity_polling() too, but the result was the same buddy!

Comment: Maybe try      
"" bot.infinity_polling(timeout=10, long_polling_timeout = 5)  ""

(without quotes)

Comment: Did that fix the issue?

Comment: No, but the issue is only in the local machine. When hosted, everything is fine. The bot is working 24/7